# (discord.py) why my kick commands is not working?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'{member} Has been kicked')
```

I have my `on_command_error` event,

```
@kick.error
async def on_kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('Please specify an user')
    elif isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        await ctx.send('You do not have a perms to do that!')
    else:
        await ctx.send('There is some error')
```

and then i got  error messages in discord

discord.py version 1.5

Comment: Try to add parentheses: `@client.command()`

Answer (score 0):

```
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
@client.command()
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason="No reason provided"):
        await user.kick(reason=reason)
        kick = discord.Embed(title=f":boot: Kicked {user.name}!", description=f"Reason: {reason}\nBy: {ctx.author.mention}")
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=kick)
        await user.send(embed=kick)
```

Does this work?

Comment: does it have the permission? Like for the bots permission

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: typing.Optional[discord.Member], arg = None):
    if arg == None:
        await ctx.send("Kicked " + member.mention + ".")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Kicked " + member.mention + " for " + arg + ".")
    await ctx.guild.kick(member)
```

This should work.